# javascript code error shown undefined value

Tags: javascript

```
function abc(id, name){
   var button = '<img src="/images/abc.png" onclick="getvalue('+id+','+name+')"/>';
   $('Div1').set('html',button);
}
```

my this code is not working. it gives an error. The error is: suppose value of name is Gaurav. then it gives error Gaurav is not defined. Please help me and tell me where is error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
var button = '<img src="/images/abc.png" onclick="getvalue('+id+',\''+name+'\')"/>';
```

and i am sure, the error will not come.